# In WebSphere App Server (WAS), what is the difference between thread pool threads and message listener sessions?

Tags: websphere, ibm-was

In WebSphere Application Server, what is the difference between the threads in the Thread Pool specified under:

**Application servers** > **server** > **Message listener service** > **Thread Pool**, threads

and sessions on the Message listener

**Application servers** > **server** > **Message listener service** > **Listener Ports** > **Listener**, Maximum sessions/Maximum messages

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very brief explanation, you can find some more details here:
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-mp&topic=ListenerPort

Message listener service > Thread Pool - is the pool available for all listener ports

Maximum sessions - is a maximum number of messages processed concurrently (in separate threads) by given listener port

Maximum messages - is a maximum number of massages processed in one transaction in one thread.

PS.
Since WAS v7 listener ports are stabilized and for new applications you should use activation specs.

Comment: Re Activation spec: agree. Unfortunately I have a large legacy install running with listener ports, and the requirement was for a drop-in replacement.